# Spring webflux reactive Mono::subscribe

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Problem statement:

I am trying to save session in redis before the request is forwarded to downstream system.

```
 return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> exchange.getSession().doOnNext(session -> {
     // some code
}
}).map(WebSession::save).doOnNext(Mono::subscribe).then(chain.filter(exchange)), SAVE_SESSION_FILTER);
```

However Mono::subscribe is asynchornous is nature, and there is no guarantee that session will be stored in redis first andthen forwarded to downstream. We are facing this issue while performing performance testing with concurrent request.

Is there any way to make it synchronous.

Comment: Why are you calling mono subscribe? The calling clients are the subscribers and your application is the producer that the clients subscribe to. It should be completely removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `flatMap` operator which makes the `subscribe` unnecessary and will not progress the flow until it is finished:

```java
return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) ->
    exchange.getSession()
        .doOnNext(session -> {/* some code*/})
        .flatMap(WebSession::save)
        .then(chain.filter(exchange)), SAVE_SESSION_FILTER);
```